# how to skip push in gem-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, rubygems, jruby

```
06:10:25 INFO: --- gem-maven-plugin:1.1.5:push (default-push) @ logstash-filter-jslt ---
06:10:25 INFO: Successfully installed abc.def.xyz.logstash-filter-jslt-2.2.0
06:10:25 INFO: 1 gem installed
06:10:25 INFO: Enter your RubyGems.org credentials.
06:10:25 INFO: Don't have an account yet? Create one at https://rubygems.org/sign_up
06:10:25 INFO: 
06:10:25 INFO: HTTP Basic: Access denied.
06:10:25 INFO: Reactor Summary:
06:10:25 INFO: logstash-filter-jslt ............................... FAILURE [01:09 min]
06:10:25 INFO: logstash-filter-xslt ............................... SKIPPED
06:10:25 INFO: -----------------------------------------------------------------
06:10:25 INFO: BUILD FAILURE
06:10:25 INFO: -----------------------------------------------------------------
06:10:25 INFO: Total time: 01:31 min
06:10:25 INFO: Finished at: 2016-07-29T04:10:25+00:00
06:10:25 INFO: Final Memory: 36M/786M
06:10:25 INFO: -----------------------------------------------------------------
06:10:25 ERROR: Failed to execute goal de.saumya.mojo:gem-maven-plugin:1.1.5:push (default-push) on project logstash-filter-jslt: Execution default-push of goal de.saumya.mojo:gem-maven-plugin:1.1.5:push failed: Java returned: 1 -> [Help 1]
06:10:25 INFO: org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal de.saumya.mojo:gem-maven-plugin:1.1.5:push (default-push) on project logstash-filter-jslt: Execution default-push of goal de.saumya.mojo:gem-maven-plugin:1.1.5:push failed: Java returned: 1
```

How to skip goal push in gem maven plugin?

Comment: Could you add more detail on the scenario you are running (pom.xml, goals you are running, what is the goal)? We are running a similar issue trying to do a maven release but skipping rubygems deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PushMojo's **skip** property](https://github.com/torquebox/jruby-maven-plugins/blob/master/gem-maven-plugin/src/main/java/de/saumya/mojo/gem/PushMojo.java#L26) to avoid pushing to RubyGems.

In the command line:

```
 mvn -Dpush.skip deploy
```

Or, in pom.xml:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>de.saumya.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gem-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.5</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
      <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```